# Error in deployment: wildfly 10

Tags: java, wildfly-10

```
10:02:08,545 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./gsol.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./gsol.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jrun.servlet.file.FileServlet from [Module "deployment.gsol.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1079)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:284)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jrun.servlet.file.FileServlet from [Module "deployment.gsol.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:723)
... 6 more

10:02:08,551 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "gsol.war")]) - failure description: {
"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./gsol.UndertowDeploymentInfoService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./gsol.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jrun.servlet.file.FileServlet from [Module \"deployment.gsol.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jrun.servlet.file.FileServlet from [Module \"deployment.gsol.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./gsol.UndertowDeploymentInfoService"],
"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
10:02:08,584 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "gsol.war" (runtime-name : "gsol.war")
10:02:08,586 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./gsol.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./gsol.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jrun.servlet.file.FileServlet from [Module "deployment.gsol.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
10:02:08,691 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990/management
10:02:08,692 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990
10:02:08,692 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started (with errors) in 9210ms - Started 873 of 1127 services (3 services failed or missing dependencies, 404 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

I'm having above error when I deploy the application to wildfly 10 on Linux. I'm newbie and very low knowledge in wildfly. Thanks.

Comment: In your `web.xml` do you have an entry for a servlet class called `jrun.servlet.file.FileServlet`? If so that class is missing so you either need to add it or remove the `web.xml` entry.

Comment: Thank you. Now works fine. :)